# What would cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [B?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I'm rewriting a client/server application using Akka 2.2.0, Java 1.7.0_25 and Eclipse Juno.

I had a sample client and server working with Akka 2.0.2.
I updated to the old stable release 2.1.4 and got everything working once again.
I've just moved to the latest stable release 2.2.0.

I created a new package to add some new functionality, leaving the existing code untouched.
Something changed and now I can't launch my test cases.

Here is the stacktrace I see when I try to create an ActorSystem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [B
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:94)
at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$4.apply(Serialization.scala:154)
at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$4.apply(Serialization.scala:153)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:697)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:178)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:347)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:696)
at akka.serialization.Serialization.<init>(Serialization.scala:153)
at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:15)
at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:644)
at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:34)
at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.apply(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:77)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:568)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:575)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:103)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:98)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:64)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
```

Its complaining that it can't class load a byte array via the method descriptor style string "[B".

@som-snytt pointed out two bug reports that exactly describe the error I'm seeing.

@paul-vargas called out -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true which re-enables the old loadClass behavior.

The allowArraySyntax flag does make the ClassNotFoundException go away but other errors popped up.  The errors lead me to believe that something has gone wrong with my Eclipse/m2e/Scala-ide/Akka setup.

I imported the project into Netbeans 7.3 and did a clean and build and it worked on the first try.  I didn't even need to set allowArraySyntax.

Comment: Can you share the version of Akka and Java you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be news to everyone:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6500212

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6434149

I only looked that up due to @paul-vargas.

I observe that in trunk, `ReflectiveDynamicAccess` uses `Class.forName` as the bug report says is recommended.  See [the code on master](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/DynamicAccess.scala#L67).

Possibly, you'll want to upgrade your Akka together with your Java version.

Or, perhaps your production runtime is stuck on 1.5 but you develop on 1.7.

Comment: Those bug reports look exactly right.  I'm still not sure why this suddenly started showing up.

Answer (score 4):

May you need add the argument to VM:

```
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
```

Comment: This fixed the error I was seeing.  But I'm still at a loss for why it started showing up.  I wasn't previously setting this flag and the code was working.  After setting this flag I now a NoSuchMethodError that suggests the running code is finding old dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Old akka and scala jars were on the classpath along with the updated versions.  Not sure why it caused the above exception but the problem became obvious once Paul pointed out the allowArraySyntax flag.